# How to best design React components and state for a project list page that includes favorites?

Tags: reactjs, redux, frontend, state, react-props

I'm currently implementing a favorites feature on a website and am planning how best to design this feature in React.  I am quite new to React.

On the website there is a left side nav bar.  This side bar contains links and also has a dedicated section for 'favorite' projects.

To the right of the nav bar there is the main section.  One of the views in this section is a list of projects a user has created.  There will be a grey colored star (think of gmail) that users can click on which then makes the project a favorite.  When the star is clicked it turns yellow, the database is updated, and you will see it appear in the left nav bar.

So a few questions about this React design:

1. How to identify projects that have been previously chosen as a favorite?

   - Should I have the project list database query identify favorites (id=2, favorite=true)?
   - I will have 2 sets of React props/state, one for favorites, one for the projects list, should I use the favorites to look for a match as I loop through the main projects list?
2. How to design the component structure?

   - I suppose that the decision in question 1 might help decide this?
   - Should the state of both the favorites list and projects list be held in a parent component 1 state in the favorites component and 1 state in the project list page component (however if it's the latter I don't think I can compare the two?)

Hopefully I'm asking this question in a clear manner and as you can see I'm looking for a best practice of how to design the components and where/how to store the project info of both favorites and list of projects on the main page.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is better to use Redux to implement the favorite feature.

Please reference the below URL.

http://react-material.fusetheme.com/apps/contacts/starred

You can dispatch action like below.

[image]

This is the action.

[image]

This is the api.

[image]

The starred contact is added or removed here.

[image]

I hope this will help you to design the component.